# java applet keytool not recognized

Tags: java

I have a java JAR i want to create a signature for it i read in tutorials that in order to do that i have to open a command prompt and go to the location where my jar is and execute the keytook command. keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -alias myKey . I keep on getting 'keytool not recognized internal external command'. I did some research and if i got it well i have to go to where the keytool.exe is in java/lib . i did that and it worked .

My question is how can i apply this command on my jar ? because in the tutorial i should execute this command where the JAR is.

Thank you

Comment: Use the full path of the keytool.exe in the JAR file - i.e. "c:\\program files\\java\\jre\\lib\\security\\keytool.exe" etc or add the directory to the path of the environment before the jar is executed.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to add keytool to your path variable, or use the full path like user93353 described

Comment: What do you mean by Use the full path of the keytool.exe in the JAR file ???  how do u do that  ?  i cannot edit my JAR can i ?

Comment: The keytool is in the same place as the compiler, the jar command, etc. how have you been using those? NB it isn't java/lib either, it is in the bin directory of the JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the full path of the directory where `keytool` is located to your `Path` environment variable. This will allow you to execute `keytool` from any directory.

- Right click on `Computer` icon and select `Properties`
- Select `Advanced system settings`
- Click `Environment Variables...`
- Select the `Path` variable under `System variables`
- Click `Edit...`
- Add the missing path
- Click `OK` on all the windows that you opened

(the exact sequence of operations may vary, depending on your Windows version)